# MySQL: receive data only per months

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

Few times ago, I asked how to do to display data per month, I must told a bad explanation because I just figured out that it's not what I want :

Here's what I got :

```
$req1 = ...
AND v.date > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
AND v.date < (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))

$req2= ...
AND v.date > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
AND v.date < (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
```

But the problem, imagine that today you are the 10th June, it's going to calculate  ALL the data between the

- 10 june to the 10 may
- then the 10 may until the 10 april...

**But what I want is data :**

- from 1st may to 1 st june,
- from 1st june to 1st july...

Do you see what I mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AND MONTH(v.date)=6 AND YEAR(v.date)=2009 [to get everything in June 2009]

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
WHERE YEAR(date) = 2010 AND MONTH(date) = 5
```

to get all rows where date is in the YEAR 2010 and the fifth month of the year.

Answer (score 0):

select month(v.date), year(v.date), sum(somedatacolumn) from thetable group by month(v.date), year(v.date);

replace sum with whatever calculation you are doing